# Class 'app\Models\User' not found Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, laravel-5.4, psr-4

The message "Class 'app\Models\User' not found" appears, but I've researched in several places and none of the solutions worked.

composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database","Models"
    ],

    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

User.php:

```
namespace App\Models;

class User extends Eloquent{
    public function allUsers(){
        return self::all();     
    }   
}
```

UserController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class UserController extends Controller{    
    protected $user = null;

    public function __construct(User $user){

        $this->user = $user;

    }
    public function allUsers(){
        return $this->user->allUsers();
    }
    public function getUser($id){

    }
    public function saveUser(){

    }
    public function updateUser($id){

    }
    public function deleteUser($id){

    }
}
```

UserController alternative (not working too)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class UserController extends Controller{
    public function __construct(){          
    }
    public function allUsers(){

        $class = '\app\Models\User';
        return $class::allUsers();

    }
    public function getUser($id){

    }
    public function saveUser(){

    }
    public function updateUser($id){

    }
    public function deleteUser($id){

    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `config/auth.php` and change App\User:class to App\Models\User::class.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
```

Also change the namespace of User.php model

```
namespace App\Models;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should care about case.

```
$class = '\app\Models\User';
```

won't work but

```
$class = '\App\Models\User';
```

probably will.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once. Here's how I solved it
It was a resource file, where i called a class instance,

```
$this->user->name
```

And in the models file, I called it as

```
User::class
```

Even when the namespace was clearly App\Models

That didn't work, because the user model was in App root directory. So I changed the instance to

```
\App\User::class
```

It worked after that